# How to set values from a child component (settings page) using vuex store in a Vue.js app?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to create a "settings" component which saves selected values into a store so that all the other components can use those values to change their appearance.

#### SettingsView.vue:

One of the settings (you can also see it [on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrRNdM?editors=1010)):

```html
[...]

<p>{{ themeColor }}</p>
<v-radio-group v-model="themeColor">
  <v-radio label="light" value="light"></v-radio>
  <v-radio label="dark" value="dark"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>

[...]

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      // default value
      themeColor: 'light',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    themeColor () {
      return this.$store.state.themeColor
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeThemeColor() {
      this.$store.commit('changeThemeColor')
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

I don't know how to properly send the selected value of that setting to the store so I just created a mutation with a method (plus the need to have some default value, e.g. `themeColor: 'light'` like shown above, make it more confusing)

#### store/modules/Settings.js

```html
const state = {
    themeColor: ''
  }
  
  const mutations = {
    changeThemeColor: state => {
      state.themeColor = ''
    }
  }
  
  export default {
    state,
    mutations
  }
```

How do I do this properly, so I can then use that value in all the components?

Do I have to use something like `getters` or `actions`? I don't really know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html, I would use a computed property with getter and setter, ie

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    themeColor: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.themeColor
      },
      set (value) {
        this.$store.commit('changeThemeColor', value)
      }          
    }
  }
}
```

Note, you do not need `data` or `methods`.

---

Your store should also look more like

```js
const state = {
  themeColor: 'light' // default value
}

const mutations = {
  changeThemeColor (state, themeColor) {
    state.themeColor = themeColor
  }
}
```

---

Demo ~ https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YYbPww?editors=1011

---

For instances where you just want to display / read the `themeColor` state in your component, I recommend using the [`mapState` helper](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html#the-mapstate-helper).

```js
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  // ...
  computed: mapState(['themeColor'])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I remove that `themeColor` from the component and move it into the store I get `Property or method "themeColor" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render` and also now I can't get it as `{{ themeColor }}` whenever I need to display that value. Not sure what to do

Comment: @Un1 That's odd. The computed property should work just fine. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YYbPww?editors=1011

Comment: Thanks for the example. Do i have to add that computed get () property or something in every component that needs to display that store's value? I just tried getting that store's value in another component by putting `{{ themeColor }}` and a computed property and added `themeColor: this.$store.state.themeColor` in data of the component and I don't see anything displayed

Comment: @Un1 you want the `get()` and `set()` only if you plan on updating the value into the store via a `v-model`. FYI, computed properties (without `get`/`set`) are always functions so it should be `themeColor() { return this.$store.state.themeColor }` or you can simply use [`mapState`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html#the-mapstate-helper)

Comment: Hmm.. Yeah, I just added that exact computed property and {{ themeColor }} in template (in another component) and nothing, not even a console error. I can display it in the "settings" component - the one from where I set the value to store, but cannot display it in another component. Do you know what can cause that problem?

Comment: @Un1 you'd have to show me the code. From your comment, it looks like you simply haven't made it a function. Again, I recommend `mapState` over manually wiring everything up, eg `computed: mapState(['themeColor'])`

Comment: I figured out what was the problem, turns out I just had to specify the name of the store module as well `this.$store.state.Settings.themeColor` thank you for your help Phil!